# django view limit subquery

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have 3 models:
models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Musician(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm trying to build a view that would:
Show all persons with their albums excluding those ALBUMS rated with 1 star.
views.py:

```
inner_qs = Musician.objects.filter(Album__num_stars__exact=1).values_list('person', flat=True).distinct()
person_list = Person.objects.exclude(Musician__Album__id__in=inner_qs).distinct()
```

The query aways excludes all artists that could have had an album with 1 star.
I need something that on SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name,m.instrument, m.name, m.num_stars
    FROM Person p
  INNER JOIN Musician m ON m.person = p.id
  INNER JOIN Album a ON a.artist = m.id
      WHERE m.num_stars <> 1
```

I know that the view is excluding at the Person level, but ¿how do I exclude elements further into the db model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all fields data from linked objects (result sql will be similar to what you need):

```
Album.objects.filter(~Q(num_stars=1)).select_related()
```

And only person data:

```
Person.objects.filter(~Q(musician__album__num_stars=1))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Person.objects.filter(Musician__Album__num_stars__exact=1).values_list('person', flat=True).distinct()
```

results a sql same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.first_name, p.last_name,m.instrument, m.name, m.num_stars
    FROM Person p
    INNER JOIN Musician m ON m.person = p.id
    INNER JOIN Album a ON a.artist = m.id
    WHERE m.num_stars <> 1
```

Comment: result will not include m.instrument, m.name, m.num_stars, only person data: SELECT DISTINCT p.first_name, p.last_name FROM ...